# Keyboard shortcut to pause YouTube when it is not the active window?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

For applications such as VLC I have global function keys I can map to, for example, pause my music/video even when I have a different program running.

Is there any way to get this functionality with YouTube?

Answer (score 5):

If you use Chrome you can use the [streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen) extension.

I learned about this in this post: https://superuser.com/a/901979

Answer (score 2):

I'd say not natively in YouTube (indeed the idea of a browser allowing a web page to install a machine-level keyboard hook gives me the fear).

However, I'd recommend using an OS-specific launcher (on Windows [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) ) and bind a key to switch to your browser, select a YouTube tab and Pause.

Answer (score 2):

There is now also the chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotkeys-for-youtube-music/ggjkoecdjegahefiaibfnjgkebhijgpf

Be sure to reload the URL, or close and reopen the App (if you used "Install as App") for it